# navbar dropdown not working in bootstrap4.0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar dropdown menu isn't working, I have included the following stylesheets and js files

```
<link href='{%static "/css/bootstrap.min.css"%}' rel="stylesheet">
<link href='{%static "/css/narrow-jumbotron.css"%}' rel="stylesheet">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Even after including these the navbar dropdown isn't working

```
<nav>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills float-right">
     {% url 'home' as home %}
     {% url 'about' as about %}
     {% url 'about' as contact %}
     <li {% if request.path == home %} class="nav-item active" {% endif %}>
       <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
     </li>
     <li {% if request.path == about %}class="nav-item" {% endif %}>
       <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
     </li>
     <li {% if request.path == contact %}class="nav-item" {% endif %}>
       <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
       <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account</a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
        {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Login</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">SignUp</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">LogOut</a>
        {% endif %}
       </div>

     </li>

   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: There are some other libs required with bootstrap.js v4, like `popper.js` - look that one up?  Check your browser console and see if you see errors. On the bootstrap website they give this link for popper" `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
and load it before bootstrap.js

Comment: @KenH. It is still not working.

Comment: As I look at the Bootstrap 4 docs regarding the navbar https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ -  it looks like there are requirements that you don't have.  It seems that what you have is a bootstrap 3 vintage navbar?  Have a look at the Bootstrap 4 docs and see what is required, that should help.

Comment: @KenH. This is component is actually under **Nav**. See the [Pills with Dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#pills-with-dropdowns) Docs. Your original comment about **dependencies** is most likely the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap V4 docs page for the navbar indicate that there are required classes to make the navbar collapse and I copied the previous poster's code, and added them.  This code is working properly with the navbar collapsing at the `navbar-expand-lg` breakpoint (you can select different breakpoints using `-sm`, `-md`, `-lg`, `-xl` and you can test it and make the similar changes to your `nav` code to have it work for Bootstrap V4.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li {% if request.path==h ome %} class="nav-item active" {% endif %}>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li {% if request.path==a bout %}class="nav-item" {% endif %}>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
    </li>
    <li {% if request.path==c ontact %}class="nav-item" {% endif %}>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Login</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">SignUp</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">LogOut</a>
      </div>

    </li>

  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, its working. But I wanted to know why the code wasn't working with respect to  <ul class="nav nav-pills float-right"> and I tried to follow this example http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/narrow-jumbotron/# by also including additional feature of dropdown

Comment: @pavikirthi - there have been many changes in Bootstrap V4 compared to V3 - so in order to get the collapsible navbar, there are new classes that make it work, as well as that `popper.js`.  It's a good idea to start with the examples on the documentation page and see how they work (get them working in your environment) and then make modifications as you need to.  If you want your elements to go to the right - there must be a different class.  The navbar is using flex now - if there is a class (or you can define one) to get `justify-content: flex-end;` then it will put the links to the right

Comment: The class to put that property on the navbar to move the links to the right is `justify-content-end`, which essentially puts the CSS property `justify-content: flex-end !important;` on the elements.  @pavikirthi - if you want to align those to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding scripts in the following order.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Without adding `popper.js`, I was not able the dropdown. 
I am still trying to know more about this.
As it was never the case in regular Bootstrap.

---

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills float-right">
    <li {% if request.path==h ome %} class="nav-item active" {% endif %}>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li {% if request.path==a bout %}class="nav-item" {% endif %}>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
    </li>
    <li {% if request.path==c ontact %}class="nav-item" {% endif %}>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Login</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">SignUp</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">LogOut</a>
      </div>

    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: There were many changes in Bootstrap 4 compared to bootstrap V3 - this is one of them.  I think that the original code posted in the question looks like a navbar that is the Bootstrap V3 style.  Check the bootstrap migration docs https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/ for additional information.